# Login to SMB share using private key

Tags: ssh, mount, nas, smb, truenas

I have a TrueNAS NAS smb share. My TrueNAS user settings have password disabled and I have added my SSH public key. I can SSH into the NAS using my private key with no issues. However, I am trying to figure out how to mount an SMB share to my linux machine.

/etc/fstab

```
//nasdomain/share /mnt/nas/share cifs username=nasusername,uid=linuxusername,gid=linuxusername 0 0
```

When I run `sudo mount -a`, I am promted to login to the share as `nasusername`. How do I login using my private key?

Is it possible to even login using key-pairs or does SMB only support user/pass? If impossible, what's the goto NAS fileshare that can use key-pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't – the SSH keys are *only* useful for SSH, which SMB is not.

SMB only supports NTLM (password-based) and Kerberos (MS AD) authentication. For NTLM auth (which is the only option on most non-AD systems), the SMB server will likely have its own password database separate from the rest of the OS.

*(Kerberos supports private-key authentication, but it's still completely different from SSH keys.)*

Use the `sshfs` or `fuse.sshfs` filesystem type for SSH-based SFTP file access (you'll need to have the sshfs package installed on the client). The performance of SFTP might be slightly worse than that of SMBv3.

Comment: So I could use SMB CIFS (not SSHFS) using Kerberos auth?

Comment: Yes, if you have the Kerberos infrastructure already (e.g. MS AD, FreeIPA, or a homegrown KDC) – but although basic Kerberos is easy, setting up public-key PKI for Kerberos (and then making Linux use it) is usually quite a bit more annoying than sshfs with SSH keys, so I wouldn't bother.